# Fake input device in Docker container on Ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, alsa, pulseaudio

I need a fake microphone device in a Docker container on an Ubuntu VM.  Any idea how I can get one there?

I'm a bit of a Linux n00b, so I've been looking at pulseaudio, ALSA and modprobe.  But I really can't tie together all the pieces, conceptually.  I'm looking to you, SO, for some much needed help on this one.

Comment: How much of a fake? Does it need to run at the correct speed? Give specific samples? And what has programming to do with this?

Comment: Well, I really just need chrome to return an audioinput device from it's `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` call.  So, pretty much anything would do.  I need to visit my page in a docker container for testing, but for some reason, the dev's WebRTC code in the page's JS thinks that no one is listening if there isn't an actual microphone device hooked up.  So I'm trying to create a fake device of some sort in the docker container so that Chrome returns something from that call.  I was able to get a fake `output` device by just running pulseaudio in the container, but no input device.

Comment: ALSA has the `null` software device, which generates zero samples at infinite speed. But I don't know how to configure PulseAudio to show it, or if PA has another, similar mechanism. Try asking on the PA mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our Firefox automated testing in CI we use PulseAudio's `module-sine-source` as a fake audio input. It just generates a sine wave. I'm not certain if the same code will work for Chrome but you can try it:
https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/2a3a253806d129c0bb6f2b76bf75630457a24492/testing/mochitest/runtests.py#736

We essentially just run `pactl load-module module-sine-source` if the module is not already loaded, and then we set a Firefox preference to force it to use that device as the default input device (but it's the only input device so it should work either way).